# Meteor app is blank in DigitalOcean

Tags: javascript, meteor, digital-ocean

I have deployed a Meteor.js app to DigitalOcean, but my app is blank. When you visit http://tremaincollege.com/ you can see that the page is blank.

I used Meteor Up to deploy and everything deployed successfully, but nothing is displaying on the domain. When I view the page source it shows the  tags exist with other tags inside, but the  tags are empty.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using mup or mupx? Please post your `mup.json` file.

Comment: I had this problem, make sure your public/auth/global routes are setup correctly. I ran into the issue where my index.html was not being routed to in the right spots

Comment: Additionally, these errors came up when i loaded the page: `The connection to ws://www.tremaincollege.com/sockjs/011/byjn24x4/websocket was interrupted while the page was loading. efb3e10d7142f4682029c83968cd7525306a471a.js:32'

'TypeError: t.fn.popover is undefined efb3e10d7142f4682029c83968cd7525306a471a.js:98'

'ReferenceError: Spacebars is not defined`